# Курсор в словаре данных

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Подскажите, существует ли какое-либо представление в словаре данных Oracle, в котором указан курсор и название таблицы, на которую он указывает?

Если такого нет, из каких представлений можно выбрать эту информацию?

Comment: Курсор это динамическое понятие, доступен только тому, кто его открыл. И зачем бы ему быть в словаре данных

Answer (score 9):

Курсор указывает на SQL выражение, не на таблицу. Если точнее - курсор это логический указатель на контекстную область памяти в UGA (*user global area*) сессии пользователя, которая содержит информацию о выполнении  конкретного SQL выражения. Информация о курсорах содержится в динамических виртуальных таблицах, или так называемых `V $views`, которые динамически обновляются на основе информации из структур памяти БД, транзакционально независимы и не попадают под категорию словарей данных БД.

Открытые курсоры с текстами SQL выражений, на которые они "указывают", можно посмотреть так:

```
select  saddr, 
        sid, 
        user_name, 
        sql_id, 
        sql_text, 
        cursor_type 
from    v$open_cursor 
where   user_name<>upper('sys');
```

Если в сессии включено кеширование курсоров (`session_cached_cursors>0`),
то можно посмотреть закрытые курсоры в кеше:

```
select oc.user_name, 
       oc.sid, 
       sql.sql_text
from   v$open_cursor oc 
join   v$sql sql 
on     (oc.sql_id=sql.sql_id and oc.sid=oc.sid)
where  user_name <> upper('sys');
```

Часто интересует только статистика - сколько открытых курсоров в каждой сессии:

```
select a.value "cursors open", 
       s.username, 
       s.sid, 
       s.serial#
from   v$sesstat a, 
       v$statname b, 
       v$session s
where  a.statistic# = b.statistic#  
and    s.sid=a.sid
and    b.name = 'opened cursors current'
order  by 1 desc;
```