# Неявные курсоры при выборке данных

Tags: oracle, plsql

Дали вот такой билет с вопросами. Может кто-то дополнить или подсказать, какие примеры можно привести еще.

И касательно выборки данных из БД немного не понял. Судя из теории, которую читал, в любом случае когда происходит выборка данных создается неявный курсор, или есть исключения?

> **Вопрос 17**
> Курсоры. Их назначение и использование. Выборка данных из БД в
> программах PL/SQL без использования курсоров. Использование неявных
> курсоров. Покажите, как можно использовать неявный курсор в вашей курсовой
> работе.
>
> Курсоры являются одним из механизмов, использующих SQL, для обработки
> данных, хранящихся в БД.
> **Курсор** - это рабочая область SQL-оператора, расположенная в оперативной
> памяти (по сути - указатель). Когда приложение посылает SQL-оператор
> серверу Oracle, сервер открывает по меньшей мере один курсор для
> обработки этого оператора. Для простых операторов INSERT, UPDATE и
> DELETE курсоры открываются автоматически. Это также относится к
> операторам SELECT ... INTO, возвращающим одну строку. Такие курсоры
> называются **неявные**.
> Для выборки из таблиц БД произвольного множества строк программист
> должен явно создавать курсор в своей программе.

В качестве примера кода с неявным курсором нашел вот такой пример, но он какой-то скучноватый:

```
DECLARE 
   total_rows number(2);
BEGIN
   UPDATE firm
   SET fbudget = fbudget + 500;
   IF sql%notfound THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('бюджет не найден');
   ELSIF sql%found THEN
      total_rows := sql%rowcount;
      dbms_output.put_line( total_rows || ' фирмам был увеличен доход');
   END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: Сопутствующие темы были [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729351/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-for-in-loop-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-plsql) и [там](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575706/%d0%9a%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-oracle)

Comment: Примеры кода в вопросе по возможности приводите как текст а не картинку.

Comment: Там задании сказано явно "_Покажите, как можно использовать неявный курсор в вашей курсовой работе_". Зачем же искать левые примеры в интернете, придумайте свои примеры на основе того, с чем работаете.

Answer (score 2):

Покажите пример, который покажет неточности в тексте задания:

> Для выборки из таблиц БД произвольного множества строк программист должен явно создавать курсор в своей программе.

Курсор *всегда* будет создан неявно, если он не был прежде объявлен явно.
Ниже будут неявно созданы два курсора, которые обработают несколько строк. Они делают одно и то же. Но есть отличие - второй вариант не устанавливает атрибуты неявного курсора. В выводе после второго курсора значения, которые установил первый: `3 rows found`, не 2.

```
create table t (id, val) as
    select rownum, trim (column_value) from xmlTable ('"abc","def", "123"')
/
declare
    type trows is table of t%rowtype;
    r trows;
    procedure printcursor is begin
        dbms_output.put_line ('cursor '||case when sql%isopen then 'open' else 'closed' 
            end||' '||sql%rowcount||' rows '||case when sql%notfound then 'not ' 
            end||'found');
    end;
begin
    /* неявный курсор 1 */
    select * bulk collect into r 
    from t;
    printcursor;
    /* неявный курсор 2 */
    for r in (select * from t where rownum<=2) loop null;
        dbms_output.put_line ('row: id='||r.id||' value='||r.val);
    end loop;
    printcursor; 
end;
/

cursor closed 3 rows found
row: id=1 value=abc
row: id=2 value=def
cursor closed 3 rows found
```